# How to serialize browser HTML DOM to XML?

Tags: html, xml, dom, serialization

I need to serialize browser parsed HTML DOM to well-format XML.

In firefox (gecko), this works:

```
// serialize body to well-format XML.
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.body);
```

But in webkit, result is equivalent to document.body.outerHTML, not well-format XML (for example: `<br> won't become <br />`)

How to serialize browser HTML DOM to XML in webkit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a `setInnerXHTML` method (not the Facebook version) which should work for this.  The method is included in the base framework file, `hemi.js`, available from the [Hemi Project Page](http://www.whitefrost.com/Hemi/). It is also included in my older `libXmlRequest` library.

Example:

```
var oXml = Hemi.xml.newXmlDocument("Xhtml");
Hemi.xml.setInnerXHTML(oXml.documentElement, document.documentElement, oXml);
var sSerial = Hemi.xml.serialize(oXml);
```

If you want to test this on a particular browser, navigate to the Hemi Project Page, click the upper-right tool icon, and click the <kbd>Active Source</kbd> tab. Copy and paste the sample code into the textarea and click <kbd>Eval Source</kbd> (the response will be a node name). Type in `sSerial` into the input field and hit enter, or click <kbd>Eval</kbd>, and you should see the serialized XML of the copied HTML DOM.